# Is there a way to access an ILB ASE from a VM on another Zone?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, vnet

We have two Front-end VMs. One inside a VNET in WE zone and the other one is a VM inside a VNET in NE. There some apps on those machines that should call our private/back-end services which are deployed inside and ILB ASE on WE zone.

There is no problem accessing BE services from FE machine in WE zone using VNET Peering. But, so far my attemps have been unsuccesful to do the same for the VM in NE zone. As far as I understood from Azure docs; it is not possible to do so.

Is there a workaround for a VM in one zone to access an ILB ASE which is deployed in another zone?

Comment: Please limit acronyms you do not define :). As for your question, what is the status of the vnet peering? Initiated? Connected? Is there is Network Security Groups associated to any of the vnets/subnets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a Basic load balancer (ILB) doesn't work over global virtual network peering, you can connect to these resources via ExpressRoute or [VNet-to-VNet through VNet Gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal). Read Azure document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#what-are-the-constraints-related-to-global-vnet-peering-and-load-balancers

Perhaps, there is another option for HTTP or HTTPS traffics. You could set up a proxy or jump box VM in the same VNet as your ILB ASE. Instead of VNet peering, the proxy will help forward your FE requests to your backend services.

- [Integrate your ILB App Service Environment with the Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/integrate-with-application-gateway)
- [Using NGINX Plus with Azure App Service to Secure Applications](https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-applications-microsoft-azure-app-service-nginx-plus/)